# How to Play URL of Live Radio Streaming URL in iOS

Tags: ios

My Radio URL is http://s2.yesstreaming.net:7091/stream and I am not able to play this URL in my Xcode project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [VLCKit](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MobileVLCKit) for it.
I have tested, it handle the given link.

I don't know if you're coding in Swift or Objective-C but here is a very simple example in Swift.

```
let mediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer()

mediaPlayer.media = VLCMedia(url: "http://s2.yesstreaming.net:7091/stream")

// outputView is the view where you want to display the stream
mediaPlayer.drawable = outputView
mediaPlayer.play()
```

Answer (score 1):

After checking the url (http://s2.yesstreaming.net:7091/stream) response header for `Content-Type`, it shows `application/ogg`.

So it can be confirmed that this radio is playing music in `ogg` format but sadly `AVPlayer` does not play this music format because Apple does not have native support for it.

---

#### Solutions:

1. Use third-party [OrigamiEngine](https://github.com/ap4y/OrigamiEngine)
    instead of `AVPlayer`
2. Use an `FFmpeg` library to decode the ogg stream before playback.

Comment: I've checked this url with `AVPlayer` now (4.3.21) and it's playing the stream. Maybe Apple added support for `ogg` since this answer.

Comment: @YonathanGoriachnick Hm... surprising at first but its the url that has changed from streaming `application/ogg` to `audio/mpeg`.